# upgrade kura installation without losing configuration

Tags: osgi, equinox, iot, kura

I'm currently running Kura 1.1.1 on a beagle bone black running debian linux with some custom packages and some altered configuration.

I would like to upgrade to the latest Kura release without losing the configuration and packages.

How do you upgrade while maintaining the state of a kura installation?

Comment: what do you mean with 'maintaining the state of kura installation' ? Which kind of configuration would you like to maintain? The bundles configuration?

Comment: if I configure the mqtt broker, install a 'package' for example .. i want to upgrade kura without having to re-configure/re-install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is not an official way to do this yet.
You can backup the following files and include them again after upgrading:

- `data/snapshots/snapshot_14xxx.xml` this is the file containing your bundles' configuration. Most recent changes have a higher timestamp.
- `kura/dpa.properties` this files contains a list of deployed *Deployment Packages*, installed through web-ui or DEPLOY-V1 cloudlet.
- `*.dp` the actual *Deployment Packages* installed.
- If you manually added jars or edited start scripts, you must copy/edit them again

Depending on how you upgrade, you may or may not have the previous installation deleted. Shell script installer for example changes `/opt/eclipse/kura/` symlink to the version it installs, without deleting the old one.